# Stop bot from creating duplicate channel with same name | discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am creating ticket tool for my discord bot but a user can create unlimited tickets by reacting there. However, I want the bot to dm that user to remind them that he is already having an open ticket.

This is what I have tried so far but it didn't work at all:

```
guild = await bot.fetch_guild(id)
channels = guild.text_channels
duplicate = False
name = f"{payload.member.name}'s ticket"
for channel in channels:
    if name == channel.name:
        duplicate = True
        break

if duplicate:
    await payload.member.send("You already have an open ticket")
    return
else:
    await category.create_text_channel(name, topic= topic, permission_synced= True)
    await ticket_channel.set_permissions(payload.member, read_messages= True, send_messages= True)
```

Comment: `payload.member.send` is a coroutine, it should be awaited. Also -- is there a reason why you overcomplicated the code so much?

Comment: my bad, but that's not the error at all. Console is totally silent.
No reason behind overcomplicated code

Comment: What is `name`? Are you maybe comparing an uppercase string to a lowercase one? `'NaMe == 'name'`?

Comment: Ah, check the updated code. Sorry for that, this code was an older one saved in the draft @ŁukaszKwieciński

Comment: Try adding some debug print statements, seems like a logic problem to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text channels cannot have spaces nor quotation marks in their names (it will also be converted to lowercase), a name like this `Name's ticket` will be converted to `names-tickets`.

```py
name = f"{payload.member.name.lower()}s-ticket"
for channel in channels:
    if name == channel.name:
        duplicate = True
        break
```

You can also simplify the code a lot, instead of having the for-loop you can use the `any` function

```py
duplicate = any(name == channel.name for channel in channels)
if duplicate:
    return await payload.member.send("You already have an open ticket")
```